# Jerky scroll with UIButton.layer.shadowColor

Tags: iphone, sdk, calayer, uitableview

I got a UITableView header with lots of buttons.
I use this to create a shadow on the buttons:

```
    Buttona.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    Buttona.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
    Buttona.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10.0f, 10.0f);
    Buttona.layer.shadowRadius = 7.0f;
    Buttona.layer.masksToBounds = NO;


    Buttonb.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    Buttonb.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7f;
    Buttonb.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0f, 3.0f);
    Buttonb.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0f;
    Buttonb.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

... and so on for Buttonc to Buttonf.

The scroll on the table becomes jerky with all theses buttons.

Should I get rid of the effect and just Photoshop the buttons with the shadow, or am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're only setting the shadows once right?

Comment: What do you mean once? As described I set the shadow for every button (a to f) as referred in the code above. If that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and the solution is

```
[view.layer setShadowPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)] CGPath]];
```